# Pandas: How to create a new column with the sum of another column filtered with an identifier?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

| Identifier | Contribution |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | 3 |
| Cat | 1 |
| Dog | -1 |
| Mouse | 2 |
| Mouse | 2 |

And I want to add a column, with the sum of the contributions per identifier:

| Identifier | Contribution | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 3 | 2 |
| Cat | 1 | 1 |
| Dog | -1 | 2 |
| Mouse | 2 | 4 |
| Mouse | 2 | 4 |

I have been trying with groupby, but I cannot manage to add the column with the sum of the groupby in an elegant way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Identifier')['Contribution'].transform('sum')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  Identifier  Contribution  Total
0        Dog             3      2
1        Cat             1      1
2        Dog            -1      2
3      Mouse             2      4
4      Mouse             2      4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but this works:

```
df["Total"] = df["Identifier"].map(df.groupby("Identifier").sum()["Contribution"].to_dict())
```